# Easiest way to set up a HTTP proxy/request forwarder in MAC?

Tags: macos, proxy

Here's the situation:  I am trying to show a demo for a chrome extension on MAC, and due to chrome's security policies it's only allowed to use HTTP connections to localhost. The test server I have is on another machine, and cannot be run easily on MAC. So I want a simple program running on my MAC that listens to requests on a specific port, forwards it to another machine, gets the response from there and sends it to the original requester.

I just want to get something working quickly, dont really care about features, efficiency etc. What should I do? Should I go for a proxy (and if yes, which one?) or would something easier do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply setting up a [ssh tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_shell_tunneling).

```
ssh -L <port1>:<machine2>:<port2> localhost
```

Where I want to forward requests from `localhost:<port1>` to `<machine2>:<port2>`.