# How can I set up an http proxy that does its own basic auth on mac os 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, git, authentication

Background Info:

End Goal: Perform Gerrit code reviews in Rubymine rather than on Gerrit's rudimentary web interface.

I attempted to connect with the [Gerrit IntelliJ plugin](https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-intellij-plugin#important-note-if-you-have-authentication-issues) with no success. I emailed Urs Wolfer, the main contributor, and he updated the README to include an "Important Note if you have Authentication Issues", in which he states:

> If you have correctly set up a HTTP Password in Gerrit, but still have
>   authentication issues, your Gerrit instance might be behind a HTTP
>   Reverse Proxy (like Nginx or Apache) with enabled HTTP Authentication.
>   You can identify that if you have to enter an username and password
>   (browser password request) for opening the Gerrit web interface. Since
>   this plugin uses Gerrit REST API (with authentication enabled), you
>   need to tell your system administrator that he should disable HTTP
>   Authentication for any request to /a path (e.g.
>   https://git.example.com/a). For these requests HTTP Authentication is
>   done by Gerrit (double HTTP Authentication will not work). For more
>   information see Gerrit documentation.

When I asked my system adminstrator if they could disable HTTP Authentication for any request to /a, he replied with:

> we can't disable http auth, sorry
>
> (not even for certain paths)
>
> you might be able to set up some sort of local proxy if you don't want
>   to hack on his code
>
> it'd be an http proxy that does its own basic
>   auth, not sure if something already exists for that purpose

Useful Info: I am a noob. I don't know exactly what setting up an http proxy that does its own basic auth will entail. I am concerned that I may break things.

Current progress towards solving this problem:

Looking into the following:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinyproxy
- [Easiest way to set up a HTTP proxy/request forwarder in MAC?](https://superuser.com/questions/520175/easiest-way-to-set-up-a-http-proxy-request-forwarder-in-mac)
- http://squidman.net/squidman/
- http://fiddler2.com/home
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server
- (will update with my progress)

Most promising thus far:

- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Bypass
- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35504/how-can-i-implement-authentication-in-my-proxy-server
- https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10899/authoxy

Notes:

- downloading authoxy
- authoxy has thus far proven ineffective in solving this problem
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030226161459306
- intellij has HTTP Proxy thing... dunno

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you have a proxy in your workplace that uses an authentication system that is not supported by a certain plugin.
 One way of workaround this would be to run a program or script that will behave as a local proxy, supporting the authentication system at your workplace, and implementing a simple or no authentication local proxy for the intended plugin to connect to.

So, if i read the question correctly this is what you need to do:

1. Install Python
2. Configure ntlmaps to use your company's proxy
3. Configure Gerrit plugin to use the local proxy you configured in ntlmaps

http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/

Mostly any other solution you were looking into would work also, if implemented around the same basic concept.

It is really hard to go into configuration details without previous knowledge on specifics on the authentication types, but last time I had to do something similar ntlmaps was the most simple to implement/configure in my personal experience.